# Is there a list of the largest academic journal publishers, ordered by the number of journals they publish?

Tags: publications, journals, publishers, bibliometrics

One can manually browse through scholarly publishers' websites and see the number of journals they publish, such as:

- Elsevier: ca. 4.330 journals
- SAGE: ca. 1.200 journals
- Inderscience: ca. 430 journals
- Cambridge University Press: ca. 380 journals
- Emerald: ca. 350 journals
- Hindawi: ca. 230 journals
- MDPI: ca. 200 journals

However, a manual search risks leaving out certain publishers, is prone to mistakes, and is quite time-consuming.

I would thus like to know: Is there already a comprehensive list of large academic journal publishers ordered by the number of journals they publish?

**EDIT**: I am not intending to crowdsource a full list here; such an approach would be flawed as well. The background for my question is that I would need precise data about academic journal publishers for a specific analysis, and before I go on to design a time-consuming data-collection method, I wanted to ask this question here.

Comment: Precision is probably unnecessary. The top-three will likely be high above the rest. One that's missing from your list is Springer.

Comment: I am not sure, how useful such a list would be. My spam folder is full of "publishing houses" claiming to publish 300+ journals. And in the times of online publishing, this might indeed be a true statement, as publishing a journal only requires coming up with a name and scamming some unsuspecting junior scientist into submitting their thrice rejected, flawed manuscript as the centre-piece of some special issue. No one would consider these places large publishers. On the other hand there are big places like the AAAS which publishes Science, but only 5 other journals in total.

Comment: Your university library can probably tell you what publishers they make payments to for journals.  Spinger says it publishes "more than 2900 journals". https://www.springer.com/gp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I could not find a satisfactory answer, I tried an alternative approach. This is what I came up with:

[image: Top 50 Academic Publishers sorted by Journal Count]

The methodical approach was, first, to obtain all publishers names that had supposedly at least 15 journals according to either *DOAJ*, *Publons*, *Scopus* or *Sherpa Romeo*. Secondly, I webscraped the journal portfolio of each respective publisher. Finally, I ordered the publisher by journal count.

More details in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1108/JD-04-2022-0083) (where the table is taken from) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/andreaspacher/academic-publishers).

Answer (score 8):

There are a large number of predatory publishers who publish 300+ journals of no real value. So there is no way to include all publishers.

However, if you would be satisfied with scopus indexed journals, then you can download the [excel file](https://www.elsevier.com/?a=91122), sort it based on publisher and filter it. Thus, you will get a list of publishers with the number of journals. Of course, the list will be confined to scopus indexed journals (around 40000 journals by 4000 publishers).

Comment: Thanks. After having done a bit of research, I guess that your suggestion is possibly the best available approach. There are limitations, of course: First, Scopus is selective (thought not as much as, say, Web of Science). Secondly, Scopus' excel list seems to have problems with unharmonized publisher names (see the discussion at https://github.com/greenelab/scihub-manuscript/issues/24). Anyway, I am unaware of a better approach - but I would still wait a bit and see whether other people have other suggestions before I 'accept' your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about the top academic journal publishers. Taylor & Francis, Elsevier, Springer, and Wiley come to mind. I don’t really keep up with the mergers and acquisition shenanigans in the publishing world so some of those might have been gobbled up by the others since the last time I looked.

[Here is the list of major academic publishers in the world in 2022.](https://phdtalks.org/2022/06/top-academic-journal-publishers.html)